# Modificar estado JSON en React JS

Tags: reactjs

Necesito tener en un estado de React JS varios valores, de forma que pueda modificar parcialmente el estado, alterando el valor de sólo uno de ellos.

Este código funciona y teniendo varios estados lograría el mismo resultado (aunque con mas código)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function MiComponente() {
  const [estado, setEstado] = useState({ clave1: "valor1" });

  return (
    <>
      <div>{estado.clave1}</div>
      {console.log("Cambiando valor de la clave1 a: ", estado.clave1 = "valor2")}
      <div>{estado.clave1}</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default MiComponente;
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿Esto es lícito? ¿Es mala práctica?

Comment: **No es una mala pregunta, pero posiblemente esté basada en opiniones y termine cerrada.** Lo importante lo puedes encontrar en artículos, videos y libros (como Clean Code) y excepto por cuestiones que aprovechan el paradigma del lenguaje como las clases, son aplicables en cualquiera. En algunos lenguajes no están disponibles y toca recurrir a otras estrategias.

Comment: esto esta mal, estado.clave1 = "valor2" Tenes que usar el **setEstado()** para modificar el estado.  Link ayuda https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html